# Why won't iPhone 5c update to 10.3.3?

Tags: software-update, software

When trying to perform the software update I see the message

> Unable to verify update iOS 10.3.3 failed verification because you are no longer connected to the internet.

Even though I am connected to the internet. I also tried to update through iTunes and I receive the message

> The iPhone […] could not be updated. An unknown error occurred (3014).

Comment: Have you verified the iPhone has at least a 50% battery charge when trying to update?  Also, is your iPhone jailbroken?

Comment: [Hasn't Apple stopped signing iOS 10.3.3?](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/04/apple-stops-signing-ios-10-3-3/)